# Why is JSONParsing failing in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am try to parse a son string into a PropertyBusinessObject. The string is in this format

```
[{
  "_id": "5b632dfabba4456c000002b1",
  "name": "General Comment",
  "description": "Generic comments that can be applied to anything",
  "label": "Comment",
  "_created": "2018-08-02T16:14:50.504Z",
  "comment_services": [],
  "service_attributes": [
    "5a5cb60d9d89946a0000721b",
    "5a5e29ac9d89946a0000813a"
  ],
  "category": [
    "5b3222cb65fe554d00001585",
    "5b32217665fe554d0000156f",
    "5ca7939d0eaf051400001c5f",
    "5b32214965fe554d0000156c"
  ],
  "parent": [],
  "providers": [],
  "logo": ["5ae07365f2f6cd4100001397"]
}]
```

I end up with this error

```
[EDT] 0:1:28,595 - Expected true for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 6 buffer: 
[EDT] 0:1:28,595 - Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - -1
[EDT] 0:1:28,597 - Exception during JSON parsing at row: 2 column: 3 buffer: [{

[EDT] 0:1:28,597 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.isStackHash(JSONParser.java:510)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.stringToken(JSONParser.java:631)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:210)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parseJSON(JSONParser.java:484)
    at com.codename1.properties.PropertyIndex.loadJSONList(PropertyIndex.java:657)
```

There is nothing wrong with the format of the json as far as I can see and Ive validated with a json formater. Something in it however does not seem to be to the liking of JSONParser an I can't just pin point it.

Comment: The JSON passes validation but may not be in the structure the application expects.  What is this `PropertyBusinessObject` data structure?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the parser, I pushed a fix for this [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/d653e61cb7364661ed3daa739f596e6fbe62041a). It would be available next week.